# JPA Criteria API selectCase in where clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api, case-when

I try to put selectCase into where clause with JPA Criteria API (Hibernate)

something like this :

```
where
prerequis3_.rank_ID=2
and case when aptitudest5_.state=true 
then (
            aptitudest5_.aptitude_ID in (3 , 4 , 1 , 6 , 2 , 8 , 7)
        ) 
else (
            aptitudest5_.aptitude_ID not in  (3 , 4 , 1 , 6 , 2 , 8 , 7)
        ) 
end
```

I try many deferents ways for Criteria Api, like this:

```
Predicate prank = cb.equal(prerequis.get("rank"), u.getRank());
In<Long> inClause = cb.in(astate.get("aptitude").get("id"));        
for (Aptitude a : u.getV().getAptitudes()) {
    inClause.value(a.getId());
}
SimpleCase<Boolean, Boolean> caseExpression = cb.selectCase(astate.get("state"));
    caseExpression.when( true,cb.isTrue(inClause));
    caseExpression .otherwise(cb.isTrue(inClause.not()));
Predicate finalPr = cb.and(prank, caseExpression);
cq.where(finalPr);
```

but a have always the same error

```
19:04:19.242 [http-nio-8080-exec-132] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - line 1:391: unexpected token: in
19:04:19.242 [http-nio-8080-exec-132] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - line 1:391: unexpected token: in
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: in
```

My question is : it is possible to do this with Criteria API?
if yes, how to solve this problem?

My apologies for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Predicate prank = cb.equal(prerequis.get("rank"), u.getRank());

//Get a list of ids
List<Integer> idsList = u.getV().getAptitudes().stream().map(Aptitude::getId)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
//Use in method from expression not from criteria builder
astate.get("aptitude").get("id").in(idsList);

....
```